# How do I count the number of times a specific time is between multiple time intervals (see example)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

**EDIT: Forgot to add the current formula (see bottom of post)**

I have multiple columns that store time as interval values (e.g. 10PM stored as 22, 6AM stored as 06) - see image

I need to check if a certain time is between all the different time intervals

> How do I write an Excel formula that checks if a time is between
>   multiple time intervals (e.g. is 2:30AM in between 10PM and 4AM?)?

My time intervals are stored in columns:

```
J5&K5 [i.e. J5 is the start (value: 02) and K5 is the end (value: 12)]
L5&M5
N5&O5
P5&Q5
R5&S5 [i.e. R5 is the start (value: 06) and K5 is the end (value: 18)]
```

The times I would like to check are in T1:AE5

```
e.g. T1 = 6:30AM
e.g. U1 = 8:30AM
e.g. AD1 = 02:30AM
e.g. AE1 = 04:30AM
```

Example (see image):
Count the number of times AD1 is in between:

```
J5&K5 
L5&M5
N5&O5
P5&Q5
R5&S5 (i.e. R5 is the start and K5 is the end)
```

> In this example, **the count should be 3 and stored in AD5** (it's in between J5&K5,
>   L5&M5, N5&O5)

[image: sample time intervals and times to be tested]

> Things to consider:
>
> - 00:00 and 24:00 are both stored as 24
> - Sometimes the start time is at night (e.g. 22, 24) and the end time is in the morning (e.g. 02, 04, 06)
> - Sometimes the start time is in the morning (e.g. 02 or 04) and the end time is in the afternoon (e.g. 14 or 16)

Current formula in AD1 (which can't account for the fact that 2.5 is actually in between 24 and 06)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($AD$1>INDEX(J4:S4,1,N(IF(1,{1,3,5,7,9}))))*($AD$1<INDEX(J4:S4,1,N(IF(1,{2,4,6,8,10})))))
```

^Note this is a formula provided by another Stackoverflow member when I had a somewhat simpler problem to tackle before the requirement changed

Comment: What formula have you tried?

Comment: @ScottCraner - Ah yes forgot to add that. Edited the post to reflect the current formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breaking down the formula you have:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($AD$1>INDEX(J4:S4,1,N(IF(1,{1,3,5,7,9}))))*($AD$1<INDEX(J4:S4,1,N(IF(1,{2,4,6,8,10})))))
```

- `$AD$1>INDEX(J4:S4,1,N(IF(1,{1,3,5,7,9})))` checks if AD1 is greater than the start time
- `$AD$1<INDEX(J4:S4,1,N(IF(1,{2,4,6,8,10})))` checks if AD1 is less than the end time
- Then the results are multiplied. Since `True` evaluates to 1 and `False` to 0, the multiplication only results in 1 where both conditions are met.

In logical terms:

- AD1 is greater than the start time

AND

- AD1 is less than the end time

---

The additional logic required is to count the instances where:

- AD1 is greater than the start time

OR

- AD1 is less than the end time

WHILE

- the start time is greater than the end time

This is accomplished with:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($AD$1>INDEX(J4:S4,1,N(IF(1,{1,3,5,7,9}))))+($AD$1<INDEX(J4:S4,1,N(IF(1,{2,4,6,8,10})))))*(INDEX(J4:S4,1,N(IF(1,{1,3,5,7,9})))>INDEX(J4:S4,1,N(IF(1,{2,4,6,8,10})))))
```

- `$AD$1>INDEX(J4:S4,1,N(IF(1,{1,3,5,7,9})))` checks if AD1 is greater than the start time
- `$AD$1<INDEX(J4:S4,1,N(IF(1,{2,4,6,8,10})))` checks if AD1 is less than the end time
- This time these get added together (OR'd)
- `INDEX(J4:S4,1,N(IF(1,{1,3,5,7,9})))>INDEX(J4:S4,1,N(IF(1,{2,4,6,8,10})))` checks that the start time is greater than the end time
- This third check gets multiplied (AND'd) with the result of the prior addition. This results in only counting situations in which the start time is at a later time than the end time (overnight) **and** for which AD1 is during the time period.

---

So to count all the desired situations, you should use the sum of both the original and the new parts:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($AD$1>INDEX(J4:S4,1,N(IF(1,{1,3,5,7,9}))))*($AD$1<INDEX(J4:S4,1,N(IF(1,{2,4,6,8,10})))))+SUMPRODUCT((($AD$1>INDEX(J4:S4,1,N(IF(1,{1,3,5,7,9}))))+($AD$1<INDEX(J4:S4,1,N(IF(1,{2,4,6,8,10})))))*(INDEX(J4:S4,1,N(IF(1,{1,3,5,7,9})))>INDEX(J4:S4,1,N(IF(1,{2,4,6,8,10})))))
```

Comment: Brilliant - works as intended. Like the logic of adding the first two checks and getting OR'd then AND'd.

Comment: Awesome one! This formula is really epic.

Answer (score 0):

Well, not the cleanest formula in the world, but at least it works. I'm sure there is a way to resume this formula, but I'm such a noob with SUMPRODUCT and I could not find a way.

I got this:
[image]

The formula I've used in cell `A3` is:

```
=SUM(IF(B7<A7;IF(Y(A1+24>=A7;A1+24<=B7+24);1;0);IF(Y(A1>=A7;A1<=B7);1;0));IF(D7<C7;IF(Y(A1+24>=C7;A1+24<=D7+24);1;0);IF(Y(A1>=C7;A1<=D7);1;0));IF(F7<E7;IF(Y(A1+24>=E7;A1+24<=F7+24);1;0);IF(Y(A1>=E7;A1<=F7);1;0));IF(H7<G7;IF(Y(A1+24>=G7;A1+24<=H7+24);1;0);IF(Y(A1>=G7;A1<=H7);1;0));IF(J7<I7;IF(Y(A1+24>=I7;A1+24<=J7+24);1;0);IF(Y(A1>=I7;A1<=J7);1;0)))
```

The idea is just check if `End` is less than `Start`. If true, because you are working with periods of 24 hours, then sum 24 to `End` and also to value being checked.

After that, it just check if the value is between `Start` and `End`.

But yeah, pretty dirty. I'm posting the formula, hoping somebody can resume it.

But as I said, at least it works.

Comment: The only issue I see with your solution is if the time being checked on an overnight stretch is before midnight. (i.e. 20.5 should be counted twice: sets 3 and 4. However, this solution only counts it once.)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Ah yes, this is something along the path I was going down (and realized the formula was extremely long/hard to understand (and would have resorted to VBA for easier readability)) before I thought of posting my question here.

I do like the logic and combination of sum and if here though - I can apply this to other Excel problems I have (I've been looking for something similar to this as well)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way solving the issue by using two **helper rows** (if that's an option):

[image: Helper Rows]

> The purpose of the helper rows is to find out the "true" end and start time for each start and end section using mid-day `12` as a judgement point. In other words, I have divided the time periods from 5 pairs to 10 unique time periods with its own start and end time.

To find **Start** time, enter the following formula in Cell `J6` and drag it across;

```
=IF(LEFT(J3,5)="Start",J5,IF(J5<12,0,12))
```

To find **End** time, enter the following formula in Cell `J7` and drag it across;

```
=IF(LEFT(J3,3)="End",J5,IF(J5>12,24,12))
```

An optional step, you can give a name to range `J6:S6` as **Start**, and give a name to range `J7:S7` as **End**, then you can enter the following formula in cell `T5` to count the occurrences of each given starting time:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((T$1>=Start)*(T$1<=End))
```

[image: Solution]

**EDIT#2**

It is actually possible to combine the above into one **array formula** (so avoid using actual helper rows) which needs to be confirmed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> upon finishing the formula in the formula bar.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((T$1>=IF(LEFT($J$3:$S$3,5)="Start",$J5:$S5,IF($J5:$S5<12,0,12)))*(T$1<=IF(LEFT($J$3:$S$3,3)="End",$J5:$S5,IF($J5:$S5>12,24,12))))
```

Enter the above in cell `T5` and drag it across.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks, Terry! I was going to code something like this in VBA (e.g. separating the two times and checking from 20-24 and 24-04 for Start3 and End3).

Alas I have 1,166,886 rows of data where I need to apply these formulas so I can't manually add all the helper rows (or have a separate sheet that has the helper rows). This does seem to work if I didn't have an excessive amount of data to sift through

Comment: @newtovba I have updated my solution with an alternative formula that have combined the three formulas into one. However it may not be faster than using helper rows, and yes probably your case is best solved by `vba` or `powerquery`.